# Visual studio 2019 auto removed nuget packages after debug

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

Every time I add any nuget package to my .net core application, it stays for a bit but it seems like after I start a debug and end it, the nuget package removed automatically from Visual studio project.

Is any thing changes in visual studio 2019?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching on internet I found solution on [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/510572/view.html) developer community Website.

1. Close VS2019
2. Delete the ".vs" folder
3. Open VS2019, add the NuGet package
4. Save all

I suspect "Save all" after adding a NuGet package might be key here.

Comment: Hi, we are so glad to hear that your issue is solved and thank you for your sharing. Please mark you reply as answer and that will help other community members who meet the same issue to easier search this helpful information, thanks in advance.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT your suggestion is valuable, and I am also a responsible and helpful community member, but my answer will accepted on tomorrow.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your understanding, it just a kindly reminder :)

Comment: This bug is driving me INSANE. It's not just NuGet, it's project references as well. This needs to be fixed YESTERDAY. And no, endlessly deleting .vs folder is NOT a solution. I'm literally, yes literally, editing project files with notepad so VS 2019 doesn't eff up my projects.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT it has forced our team to downgrade to VS2017, do we have this issue being tracked somewhere?

Comment: This is really an awful issue. After trying various things, found this solution. Perfect! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should see: In the `NuGet.Config` file, DisabledPackageSources tag shows you the sources which are currently disabled, so if you want to make them be active, add the sources under the ActivePackageSource. Anyway, since it works well now after you edit the DisabledPackageSources, at least, we make sure that it would be related to the `NuGet.Config`file.